# How to change indention spaces with Eslint and Prettier in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pgivens/write-cleaner-code-using-prettier-and-eslint-in-vscode-d04f63805dcd) to set up `eslint`, `prettier` in `vscode`.

It works great and real-time lint. The problem is that it is using 2 spaces for indention. Does anyone know how to make it 4 spaces.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set the [Tab Width](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) to 4. From the that link you can check all the other different options.